# JsonObjectRequest is working when i debug but not working when simply run the app

Tags: android

I am trying to parse JSON data using volley and trying to inflate it in `ExpandableListView`. When I am launching the application then flow is not going inside...

```
       JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, TRENDING_STOCKS_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ...........
        ..........

        }
```

and data is not displaying in list view, but when I am debugging the app then flow is not going inside above code but data is displaying properly.

Can anyone tell me whats happening here and what should i do for this?

Comment: pls reply as soon as possible, I stuck here. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The code inside onResponse is not skipped, instead it goes inside the call back when the response arrives, that's probably why you do see the data eventually.

This code does not run immediately, onResponse is your implementation of an interface provided by the request object, that is called when the response arrives

Read about callback handling and interfaces, it's pretty easy to understand both, for simple callbacks and networking stuff.

To see when the response does return, print the response itself (response.toString() at the beginning of onResponse) and wait a bit to see it in your log after the request is sent.

EDIT:

also make sure you are actually updating your UI members when the data is received in onResponse() ,i.e. if it's a list view make sure you call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on the adapter holding the data list, after you are sure the data has been updated (best place in your case might be inside onResponse()).
that would be:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, TRENDING_STOCKS_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
      ...// parse the response and put it inside the list<SomeData>
      ...// off-course I mean the list that's referenced in your adapter
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

    }
```

Comment: some time data is coming sometimes not in ListView. How I can overcome this problem?

Comment: debug your callback and check the service with postman, see if there is any difference

Comment: could you post your log?

Comment: 08-26 11:56:41.790    3405-3405/com.stockal.app I/stockal-app﹕ TrendingStocks loaded successfully
08-26 11:56:42.864    3405-3405/com.stockal.app I/stockal-app﹕ onAttach Called
08-26 11:56:42.864    3405-3405/com.stockal.app I/stockal-app﹕ HOMEFragment attached to the HomeView
08-26 11:56:42.942    3405-3429/com.stockal.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-26 11:56:42.942    3405-3429/com.stockal.app W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb42d1cc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Bro :) I meant edit the question and add a big portion of the log, add a print of what's going on inside onResponse so you could see if it's working properly, and add that print out to the question :) also - I'm editing my answer, look at that too

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem for a couple of days. I don't know to what extend your problem was caused by a similar situation. In my case, I am using a Singleton Volley pattern, and the problem was as follows:

Activity 1: Request JSONObject ---> returns JSONObject correctly, and fill the adapter. The adapter has an onItemClickListener that will trigger a Activity 2.

Activity 2: Request JSONObject ---> returns JSONObject correctly, and fill the adapter. Once the user is done with Activity 2, returns to Activity 1.

Activity 1: JSONObjectRequest request is created and added to Volley, but nor the onResponse, neither onErrorRespose are called afterwards.

That only happened in the run mode, but was perfectly working while debugging.

Solution: 
When adding request to volley be sure you add a different tag on each activity. When moving to another activity be sure to cancel all request with the activity tag. That solved my problem.